# need help with android xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to get this list item layout for my application-

I tried using relative layout with linearlayout for the color and textview for the text but that doesnt get the desired result. Can anyone please help? 
here is the code I have tried which doesnt give the desired output - 
Here's the code I have tried -
    Here's the code I have tried -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#98F5FF"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:textSize="25dip"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:text="This is text1"/> 
 </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: listitem]

Comment: Please post your layout xml and specify what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `RelativeLayout` on the top of the hierarchy, which would have 1 `LinearLayout` as the first Layout on the bottom (For the background as you say) and 3 others views positioned on the top for the rest of the elements. In the `LinearLayout` you can set the desired percentage of green background with `android:layout_weight` parameter.